# How can we prove this equation using marginalization and conditioning?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I want to prove $$P(A|C) = \sum_{B} P(AB|C) $$ How can we prove this using marginalization and conditioning?

Comment: Summation over what? A covering of disjoint events maybe?

Comment: Yes, all of them are disjoint.

Comment: And covering as well? Btw, that data must be added to your question. Mentioning it in a comment is not enough.

Comment: I think I have an answer for you, but that will only appear if the question is improved.

Comment: It's just a marginalization formula generalized to include three events.

Comment: I am not asking for a comment but for an improvement of your question by means of an [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1796919/edit)

Comment: He talks about them at 43:00 something - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jY2E6ExLxaw&index=8&list=PLE6Wd9FR--Ecf_5nCbnSQMHqORpiChfJf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I preassume that $AB$ is an abbreviation of $A\cap B$ here, and that we are dealing with disjoint events $B_1,B_2,\dots$ that cover the whole space.

Also I just don't know what is meant by marginalization and conditioning, but here is a direct route to prove the statement.

We have the general rule: $$P(S|R)P(R)=P(SR)\tag1$$

leading to:

$$\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(AB_{n}|C\right)\right]P\left(C\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(AB_{n}|C\right)P\left(C\right)=$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(AB_{n}C\right)=P\left(AC\right)=P\left(A\mid C\right)P\left(C\right)$$
The third equality is a consequence of $AC=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}AB_{n}C$ where the $AB_{n}C$ are
disjoint.

So if $P\left(C\right)>0$ then we can divide by it and are allowed to conclude that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(AB_{n}|C\right)=P\left(A\mid C\right)$$

---

I'll try to shed some light on what I saw in the video. According to the rule (1) we have:$$P(A|BC)P(B|C)P(C)=P(A|BC)P(BC)=P(ABC)=P(AB|C)P(C)$$

Again dividing by $P(C)$ we find:$$P(A|BC)P(B|C)=P(AB|C)$$

Comment: Quote: "that will only appear if the question is improved." :-)

Comment: @Did Yes, I admit: I couldn't resist anymore.

Comment: *Schade*. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Next time I will resist. Promise! I have improved on this, but still am not strong enough. There is hope, though.

Comment: @drhab Thanks! Are Probabilities like P(ABC) = P(CBA) = P(CAB) = P(BAC) = P(ACB) = P(BCA) etc are all equal?

Comment: Yes, because the sets $ABC$, $CBA$ etc. are the same: $A\cap B\cap C=C\cap B\cap A$